# Mackey topology on $X'$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Does the Mackey topology $\tau(X',X)$ coincide with the operator norm topology on the dual $X'$ of a normed space $X$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take these facts:

1. If $X$ is a normed space, the strong topology $\beta(X', X)$ coincide with the norm topology of $X'$.
2. A locally convex space $X$ is semireflexive iff $\beta(X',X) = \tau(X',X)$. This is a conclusion of the Mackey-Arens theorem.
3. A normed space $X$ is reflexive iff it is semireflexive.

From these points you see, that the answer to your question is: "if and only if $X$ is reflexive".

Comment: Maybe it would be better to phrase it: "from these points you can deduce that"...